# Using Recursion and Accumulators in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, accumulator

I'm experimenting with guard recursion, but I'm having a difficult time with Haskell syntax.
I'm trying to use recursion in Haskell to reduce an integer 'n' number of times until it reaches my desired base case, while keeping track of 'n', then return the reduced integer and 'n' as a tuple for my piece of information.

My base case would be when the integer is within 1 to 13.

For example,

```
Prelude> reduce 42
(3, 2)

Prelude> reduce 3
(3, 0)
```

To explain the logic,

```
Prelude> reduce 42
( (((42 - 13) - 13) - 13), 1+1+1+1 ) --> assume the accumulator = 0, hence 0,1,2.
(3, 3)

Prelude> reduce 3
(3, 0) --> already in base case!
```

Currently, I have

```
reduce (x, 0)
  | x `elem` [1 .. 13] = (x, acc)
  | otherwise = reduce (x -13, acc + 1)
  where
    acc = 0
```

But of course, my IDE is yelling that I'm wrong. I have no clue how to implement initialize tuples into this recursion so that it's like `reduce :: a -> (a, b)`

EDIT: I think I'm getting closer...but of course, I'm trying to implement it as `a -> (a,b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialise it with a helper function:

```
reduce::Int->(Int,Int)
reduce x = reduce' (x,0)

reduce'::(Int,Int)->(Int,Int)
reduce' (x,n)

  | elem x [1..13] = (x,n) 

  | otherwise = reduce' (x-13,n+1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've seen that particular syntax where there is an apostrophe (') applied at the end of function names numerous times on tutorials when initializing variables.. could you explain the difference between reduce and reduce'? Is it mandatory to use the apostrophe?

Comment: @lattejiu: An apostrophe in a Haskell variable/function name is meant to look like a “prime” in math notation. It’s used as a naming convention for pairs of things that are related, when you don’t want to come up with distinct names. Here `reduce'` is just a “helper” for `reduce`. Sometimes a prime means “strict” (e.g. `foldl'` / `foldl`, `modifyIORef'` / `modifyIORef`). Sometimes it means “updated” (e.g. `x' = x + 1`), although it’s best to limit that, so you don’t end up trying to tell the difference between `x'''''` and `x''''''`. You could also use it in a regular name, e.g. `don't`.

Answer (score 4):

Using an accumulator parameter is a fine approach, and indeed the most efficient one, provided you manage laziness correctly with `seq`. However, an arguably simpler technique, perhaps easier to learn, would use no accumulator parameter. Instead, do the recursive call and then modify its result:

```
reduce x | x `elem` [1..13] = (x, 0)
         | otherwise = let (y, n) = reduce (x - 13)
                       in (y, n + 1)
```

It further turns out that there is a cute shortcut for "modify the second element of a tuple" - I wouldn't recommend using this in your first programs, but it's an interesting taste of what may be to come:

```
reduce x | x `elem` [1..13] = (x, 0)
         | otherwise = succ <$> reduce (x - 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Underscore is not allowed in this position.

```
reduce::Int->Int                                                                                                                                                                        
 reduce x
    | elem x [1..13] = x
    | otherwise = reduce (x - 13)
```